# Unmount nested mounts not working after unmounted root of nest

Tags: mount, xen, xfs

I have a XEN Server, which I can't reboot. My boss has filesystems mounted as such strange way:

`/mnt/hda1/hda2`

Then he unmounted them as such

`umount /mnt/hda1/`

Now he can't unmount hda2 anymore. What can he do to recover the situation without a reboot?

Comment: Is `hda2` still listed as mounted? If so, try remounting `hda1` first and then unmounting cleanly.

Comment: Not working, will mount itself on top.

Comment: ..and yes to your other question. the hda2 is still listed as mounted.

Comment: What error message do you get when you call `umount /dev/foo` where `/dev/foo` is the device mounted at `/mnt/hda1/hda2`?